# Solving for $x$ in $10.000\times 1,0877^{x-20} = 8.028.000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not good with math, so you could really help me out.
I have this formula:

> $$10.000\times 1,0877^{x-20} = 8.028.000$$

What is $x$? Can I do the following?

> $$10.877^{x-20} = 8.028.000$$

And then what?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do your points represent?

Answer (score 4):

No you can't since

$$A\cdot B^{(x-20)}\neq (A\cdot B)^{(x-20)}$$

we need to proceed as follows

$$A\cdot B^{(x-20)}=C \implies B^{(x-20)}=\frac C A \implies \log_B\left(B^{(x-20)}\right)=\log_B\left(\frac C A\right)$$

$$\implies x-20=\log_B\left(\frac C A\right) \implies x=20+\log_B\left(\frac C A\right)\implies x=20+\frac{\log \left(\frac C A\right)}{\log B}$$

where we have used that $\log x^y=y\log x$ and $\log_x y= \frac{\log y}{\log x}$.

Comment: Wow. Respect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @FrankWessels You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by $8.028.000$ you mean $8028000$?

$x \approx 20.72 $

Since:

$10000\times(10877)^{(x-20)} = 8028000 $ implies $10877^{(x-20)} = {8028\over10}$

and so $ x-20 = {{\ln({8020\over10})}\over{\ln(10877)}} \approx 0.72$

Apologies if I have interpreted the question wrongly. If you just need the answer to this kind of thing https://www.wolframalpha.com/ can solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

$$10000\cdot1,0877^{x-20}=8028000$$
To solve for $x$, first divide left and right side by $10000$:
$$1,0877^{x-20} = 802,8$$

If right-side = left side then use natural log: $\ln($leftside)$=\ln$(rightside).
So:
$$\ln(1,0877^{x-20}) = \ln(802,8)$$

Apply log-rule: $log_a(x^b) = b\cdot log_a(x)$ on $1,0877^{x-20}$: $\ln(1,0877^{x-20}) = (x-20)\cdot \ln(1,0877)$

We then get
$$(x-20)\cdot \ln(1,0877) = \ln(802,8)$$
Move $\ln(1,0877)$ to right hand side:
$$x-20 = \frac{\ln(802,8)}{\ln(1,0877)}$$
Move $-20$ to right side to get x:
$$x = \frac{\ln(802,8)}{\ln(1,0877)} + 20$$

$x$'s real solution is more approximately equal to $99,5584$

thats also close to a hundred:
$$x \approx 100$$

From your original equation: $10000\cdot 1,0877^{x-20}=8028000$ we can check if the right-hand side is close to $8028000$.

To check the validity of the real solution we can plug in the closest value we found for $x$:

First set $x=99,5584$.
$$10000\cdot 1,0877^{99,5584-20} =$$
$$10000\cdot 1,0877^{79,5584} =$$
$$8028009.0145...$$

which is close to $8028000$, and $x$'s approximation is close.